# Failed importing file in SQL Server Managment studio

Tags: database, t-sql, file-upload

In SQL Server Management Studio I exported a table from one database to an .xslx file, then imported it to another database on a different server. It failed to import and gave the following details:

> - Validating (Error)
>     Messages
>     • Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "QuestionID".
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> • Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> • Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination - HJFast_Track" (47)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> • Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is that QuestionID is an auto-incrementing identity field. In order to insert values into that column you'll need to specify.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON
```

Your other option *if that field is an auto-increment identity* is leave it out of the import/export and let the sql engine generate keys like it would for any other insert.

Without having the schema of your table in front of me a guess is as good as I can offer.

If you update your question with the structure of the table your trying to insert that might give other clues.  For example, if QuestionID is a guid or something.